# In C#, GroupBy a property which is a List

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

*Grouping by* a property which is a `List<T>` doesn't work.
What is the best way to adjust it?

```
var blocks = new List<Block>();

blocks.Add(new Block()
{
    Id = 1,
    Values = new List<int>() {1, 2}
});

blocks.Add(new Block()
{
    Id = 1,
    Values = new List<int>() { 2, 3 }
});

blocks.Add(new Block()
{
    Id = 2,
    Values = new List<int>() { 1, 2 }
});

blocks.Add(new Block()
{
    Id = 2,
    Values = new List<int>() { 2, 3 }
});

// here I have 2 groups, which is good
var g1 = blocks.GroupBy(b => b.Id);
// here I have 4 groups, I expected 2
var g2 = blocks.GroupBy(b => b.Values);

public class Block
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement an `IEqualityComparer<List<int>>` to pass to `blocks.GroupBy(b => b.Values, yourComparer)`. Your current code compares and groups by the **reference** of `Values`, not the content of these lists.

Comment: Which `List<int>` are suuposed be *equal*? 1. If list has the same items in the same order? Or, 2.  If list has the same items (order doesn't matter) Or 3. Something else?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, in this case, Lists are supposed to be equals if they contain the same items whatever the order. But I am interested to know the solution for both cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are going to compare list you have to provide a comparer (which lists are treated as equal?) In case lists are equal if and only if 
they have *same items* in the *same order*:

```
{1, 2} != {1}        // wrong items number
{1, 2} != {1, 2, 3}  // wrong items number
{1, 2} != {1, 3}     // wrong items values
{1, 2} != {2, 1}     // wrong items order 
{1, 2} == {1, 2}
```

the comparer can be

```
public class MyListComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>> {
  public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y) {
    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj) {
    return obj == null ? -1 : obj.Count;
  }
}
```

and the *Linq*

```
var g2 = blocks.GroupBy(b => b.Values, new MyListComparer<int>());
```

**Edit:** In case we want to ignore order, we can implement a bit different comparer:

```
public class MyLeanListComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>> where T : IComparable<T> {
  public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    else if (null == x || null == y)
      return false;

    return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.OrderBy(item => item), y.OrderBy(item => item));
  }

  public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj) {
    return obj == null ? -1 : obj.Count;
  }
}
```